# "order by" based on a expression

Tags: java, xpath, jcr, jcr-sql2

Given a comparator:

```
public int compareTo(Person p1, Person p2)
{
    String val1 = StringUtils.isEmpty(p1.nickName) ? p1.name : p1.nickName;
    String val2 = StringUtils.isBlank(p2.nickName) ? p2.name : p2.nickName;

    return val1.compareTo(val2);
}
```

I'd like to achieve the same result with "order by" using a xpath query (or SQL2 if it's beyond xpath's capabilities). Is it possible?

Given data:

```
No. |  Name    | Nickname |
 1  |  Adam    | Hornet   |
 2. |  Adam    |          |
 3. |  Jack    | Legend   |
```

Sorted data:

```
No. | name | nickname
2.  | Adam | 
1.  | Adam | Hornet
3.  | Jack | Legend
```

Comment: It would help if you put some data set and the exact output you are expecting

Comment: @RobertoSanchez: data provided

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in both JCR-SQL2 and XPath.

**Standard JCR-SQL2**

Assuming you have a node type called `Person` with `name` and `nickname` fields, then one way to achieve something close to your desired results in JCR-SQL2 is:

```
SELECT p.name, p.nickname FROM Person AS p ORDER BY p.name ASC, p.nickname ASC
```

But we can write this query a little more plainly because there is just a single selector (i.e., a single "table"), and we can leave off the optional `ASC`

```
SELECT name, nickname FROM Person ORDER BY name, nickname
```

Now, strictly speaking the results you get from this query will be dependent upon the implementation, and that's because you described in your question how the `nickname` field might be null, and the JCR 2.0 specification does not specify how the ordering deals with `NULL` values. For example, should they appear before or after non-null values? The implementation gets to pick.

There's another sticky issue. Notice that I've assumed that the `Person` node type has a `name` field, rather than assume that you're storing the name of the person in the node's name. That's because in JCR-SQL2 you have to access the node's name using a special function named `NODENAME` or `NODELOCALNAME`. You can use this directly in the ordering, but unfortunately obtaining the node's name in the query results is not defined in standard JCR-SQL2.

So the following query using standard JCR-SQL2 would work:

```
SELECT nickname FROM Person ORDER BY NODELOCALNAME, nickname
```

but you'd have to get the node's name from the `javax.jcr.Node` obtained from the results rather than one of the values in the result set. Strictly speaking, this is neither expensive nor difficult; it just changes how your application uses the query results.

**JCR-SQL2 in ModeShape**

One JCR implementation, ModeShape, extends the standard JCR-SQL2 grammar with a number of [additional features](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE/JCR-SQL2#JCR-SQL2-ExtensionstoJCRSQL2). One of those extensions is to introduce several *pseudo-columns*, including:

- `jcr:name` is a stand-in for the node's name
- `jcr:path` is a stand-in for the node's path
- `mode:localName` is a stand-in for the local part of the node's name
- `mode:depth` evaluates to the depth of the node
- `jcr:uuid` evaluates to the result of `javax.jcr.Node.getUUID()`

So you can use the `jcr:name` pseudo-column both in the ordering and in the SELECT clause:

```
SELECT jcr:name, nickname FROM Person ORDER BY jcr:name, nickname
```

Those options are available in ModeShape 3.x. But the community is currently working on ModeShape 4.0 (currently in Alpha), and one more extension has been added: you can specify whether [nulls should come first or last](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODE40/JCR-SQL2#JCR-SQL2-ExtensionstoJCRSQL2) in an ordering. Here's a variation of the earlier query that shows how to use it:

```
SELECT name, nickname FROM Person ORDER BY name NULLS FIRST, nickname NULLS FIRST
```

If you're `Person` node type definition ensured that the `name` property were mandatory (never null), you wouldn't need to specify the `NULLS FIRST` (or `NULLS LAST`) on the `name` column ordering.

Here's the same query except with `jcr:name` rather than `name`:

```
SELECT jcr:name, nickname FROM Person ORDER BY jcr:name, nickname NULLS FIRST
```

Notice that we didn't need to specify `NULLS FIRST` or `NULLS LAST` on the `jcr:name` column, since every node has a name and thus `jcr:name` will never be null.

**Standard JCR 1.0 XPath**

If you're using a JCR implementation that still supports XPath (which technically was specified as part of JSR-170, or JCR 1.0, and was deprecated in JSR-283, or JCR 2.0), you can also use XPath:

```
//element(*, Person) order by @name ascending, @nickname ascending
```

Since JCR 1.0 does define the `jcr:name` pseudo-column, you can actually pretty easily use the node's name:

```
//element(*, Person) order by @jcr:name ascending, @nickname ascending
```

One more thing: ModeShape 3.x or later parses queries written in JCR-SQL2, XPath, and JCR-SQL into the same abstract syntax tree and then executes them. Therefore, the last JCR-SQL2 query and last XPath query would be processed identically in ModeShape.

Comment: My case is not select * from person order by name, nickname. It is select * from person order by (use nickname or if it's null use name). If "name" is a restricted keyword use workphone and mobilephone as field names. It's irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of how you can do it with arbitrary code in your comparator.  Take the `NodeIterator` that you get from executing an ordinary query:

```
import javax.jcr.query.Query;
import javax.jcr.query.QueryManager;
import javax.jcr.query.QueryResult;
import javax.jcr.query.NodeIterator;
import org.apache.jackrabbit.commons.iterator.NodeIteratorAdapter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;

. . .

Query query = queryManager.createQuery( /* query without any ordering specs */ );
QueryResult queryResult = query.execute();
NodeIterator nodeIterator = queryResult.getNodes();
```

and pass it to a method that performs the sort and returns another `NodeIterator`:

```
NodeIterator sortedNodes = sortMyWay(nodeIterator);

. . .

private NodeIterator sortMyWay(NodeIterator input) {
    ArrayList<Node> results = new ArrayList<Node>();
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        results.add(input.nextNode());
    }
    Collections.sort(results, new Comparator<Node>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(Node node1, Node node2) {
            String nickName1 = (node1.hasProperty("nickName") ? node1.getProperty("nickName").getString() : "");
            String nickName2 = (node2.hasProperty("nickName") ? node2.getProperty("nickName").getString() : "");
            return nickName1.compareTo(nickName2);
        }
    });
    return new NodeIteratorAdapter(results);
}
```

Retrieve your results from `sortedNodes.nextNode()` as usual.

Add exception handling to the above method as needed, and add defaulting to the `name` property as needed.

Comment: Fair enough.  I should mention that, at present, we use this pattern only for relatively small sets of reference/table lookup data.  I don't know how well it would scale for your situation.

Comment: It wouldn't. Currently to solve the problem I'm describing I'm using comparator similar to the one listed in my question. Performance is not astonishing.